# How to enable a batch file to work for any profile and user on a pc?

Tags: batch-file

As the title says, how do I allow a batch file to for example move a file from one user: C:\User\User1\Programs

to another user:

C:\User\User2\Programs

with a line of code. If I for example wanted to move the minecraft launcher from one user to another but didn't want to change the username in the batch file, I'd only have to specify the file that I want moved. I was thinking of using a variable but using C:\User%Username%\Programs doesn't work.

Tried using %Username% but it didn't work, and when trying to specify with:

SET Username=C:\User

it didn't work and it also didn't work while just using %Username% either.

Update and edit. Here is the code I was thinking:

@echo off

MOVE "test.bat" %~dp0StartUp

pause

Problem now is that it replaces the batch file with a text file that says StartUp and contains nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the username by using `set username=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Programs`